# tccv template - \SYMBOL{} in personal box

Tags: cv

I'm modifying the `tccv` template to fit it to my needs and I needed to add more information in the personal box.
This is a screen of the personal box:
[image]

I want to change the symbols, I tried to look online if there is a list with all the possible symbols using `\SYMBOL{}` but I didn't find it.
I'm looking for symbols representing gender, skype and linkedin
Do you know what can I use instead of `\SYMBOL`?

This is the part of code related to the personal box

```
\newcommand\personal[9][]{%
\newcommand\SYMBOL[1]{\raisebox{-2pt}{\Large\ding{##1}}}%
\needspace{0.5\textheight}%
\newdimen\boxwidth%
\boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
\colorbox[HTML]{F5DD9D}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|X}
\SYMBOL{45} & {#2}\smallskip\\
\SYMBOL{45} & {#3}\smallskip\\
\SYMBOL{45} & {#4}\smallskip\\
\SYMBOL{44} & {#5}\smallskip\\
\SYMBOL{43} & {#6}\smallskip\\
\SYMBOL{37} & {#7}\smallskip\\
\SYMBOL{37} & {#8}\smallskip\\
\SYMBOL{41} & \href{mailto:#9}{#9}
\ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \SYMBOL{218} & \href{http://#1}{#1}}
\end{tabularx}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`fontawesome`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome).

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\renewcommand\personal[9][]{%
    \needspace{0.5\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{F5DD9D}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|X}
    \faMale & {#2}\smallskip\\
    \faBirthdayCake & {#3}\smallskip\\
    \faFlag & {#4}\smallskip\\
    \faChain & {#5}\smallskip\\
    \faHome & {#6}\smallskip\\
    \faPhone & {#7}\smallskip\\
    \faSkype & {#8}\smallskip\\
    \faEnvelope & \href{mailto:#9}{#9}
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \faLinkedin & \href{#1}{#1}}
    \end{tabularx}}}
```

[image]

[Live example on Overleaf](https://v1.overleaf.com/read/kzyyfdcrhrpg)